# Direct Proof (Basic Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

$\forall y\in\Bbb Q\,, \exists n∈\Bbb Z~~\textrm{s.t.}~~n\leqslant y\leqslant n+1$.

I'm just unsure how to approach this. I tried applying the Euclidean Algorithm bu I haven't really gotten anywhere. I'm trying not to use the Completeness Axiom on this- just trying to do it as a basic direct proof.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more context--what is your definition of the reals, and what facts about them have you already proven?

Comment: In particular, for instance, if your definition of the reals is "a complete ordered field", then it is impossible to solve this without using the completeness axioms somewhere.

Comment: We defined them so far as the union of the set of rationals and irrationals. We have talked about the fact they are a complete ordered field but that is not our working definition of them yet.

Comment: Additionally, we talk about them as decimals or points on a number line.

Comment: You want to look at the fact the reals are Archimedean and the fact that any subsets of integers bounded to the left has a first element.

Comment: Could i also let n be the closest integer to y such that y-n⩽1?

Comment: Have you tried the Archimedean Property?

Comment: Define a set of integers less than $y$.  The set has a supremum.  Call it $n,  n+1$ must be greater than $y$

Comment: If you're okay with thinking of reals as decimal strings, then just take $y$ and lop off all digits past the decimal.

Comment: As the prior comments have said, you must have a definition of $\mathbb R$ in order to start. There are several provably equivalent def'ns of $\mathbb R.$  Always refer to the def'ns.

Answer (score 4):

Write $q=a/b$, with integer $a$ and $b$, $b>0$. The division algorithm gives you
$$
a=bn+r
$$
with integer $n$ and $r$, with $0\le r<b$. Then
$$
q=\frac{a}{b}=n+\frac{r}{b}
$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: How would i get x< n+1 though?

Comment: @Jay3 Since $0\le r<b$, we have $0\le \frac{r}{b}<1$, so $q=n+\frac{r}{b}<n+1$.